# Document library - custom formatting - hover card

Tags: document-library, json-formatting, modern-document-library

I have created a document library in Sharepoint Online.
That library serves as a photo gallery.
The photos have some custom attributes linked to our global term store.

I created a thumbnail column using custom formatting so that even in list view the user immediately sees the contents of the image.

Then I wanted to create custom hover card (since the default file hover card does not show the image content for some strange reasons).

Here's the code I created:

```
"customCardProps": {
                "isBeakVisible": true,
                "directionalHint": "rightCenter",
                "openOnEvent": "hover",
                "formatter": {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                        "class": "lb_thumbnail"
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "width": "400px",
                        "height": "400px",
                        "display": "flex",
                        "flex-direction": "column",
                        "justify-content": "center",
                        "text-align": "center",
                        "padding": "5px"
                    },
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "elmType": "img",
                            "style": {
                                "max-width": "100%",
                                "max-height": "100%",
                                "display": "block"
                            },
                            "attributes": {
                                "src": "@thumbnail.400x400"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

The result looks OK so everything is fine up to this point.

The problem is it randomly does not work.

Some thumbnails react to `hover` event perfectly, some thumbnails need to hover twice to display the card, sometimes it does not work at all.
The behavior changes when I scroll up or down the library contents. Looks like it has something to do with loading new items and re-rendering the view content as the user interacts with the page.

When I change the the event to "click", it does not work at all.

Anyone experiencing this issue?

Custom column formatting with hover cards looked like a pretty cool feature but it behaves very unreliably.

Comment: It is a really cool feature! Unfortunately, there are some issues with it right now ([6002](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6002)). This appears to be a regression on the Microsoft side. This should hopefully be addressed soon.

Comment: Are there any updates / hints on this? The posted issue is marked as solved but the problem still exists.